# Could not parse version constraint prueba: Invalid version string "prueba"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Al ejecutar el comando de crear nuevo proyecto en laravel, se devuelve el siguiente error:

```
composer create project laravel/laravel prueba
```

> Do not run Composer as root/super user! See
>   https://getcomposer.org/root for details
>
> [UnexpectedValueException]
>   Could not parse version constraint prueba: Invalid version string
>   "prueba"

¿Qué sucede? Gracias.

Comment: el comando debería ser: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel prueba` no?

Comment: revisa aquí la sintaxis de los comandos para instalar https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#installation